# How do I replace some texts in a php string

Tags: php

I want to replace `<` and `>` in a php string before inserting into the database so when a user types a code, it won't execute its function so I did this:

```
$comment = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $comment);
$comment = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $comment);
```

But I also have something like this within the string `<3msg` which I don't want to replace Please How do I run my code.

Comment: why do you want to replace it before put into db?

Comment: you have [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for that right? try [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: @nospor... like I said, when a user passes a code to the string, I don't want the code to be executed when I echo it out from the db

Comment: that's why we use `htmlspecialchars()` before `echo` not before putting into db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
$comment = str_replace("<", "&#60;", $comment);
$comment = str_replace(">", "&#62;", $comment);
$comment = str_replace("&#60;3msg", "<3msg", $comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one character at different places you need to be more specifi, for example chars which are always next to this or something else. Otherwise you are out of luck since you have to exactly identify the char(s) which you want to replace. For the scenario aboce there is a function called htmlspecialchars ([Link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php))

If you want to be sure that nothing interferes with your query and no sql injection attacks can occur I suggest that you used prepared statements as often as you can. You can read mor about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and if this is not enough I can give you examples for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sanitize database input to remove scripts etc then you can use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) like this:

```
$comment = strip_tags($comment)
```

Alternatively if you want to keep tags but not allow code injection then you can also use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) which will make a more thorough and comprehensive conversion to ensure you don't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Useing php function:

```
htmlspecialchars($comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

you can use **htmlentities()** to achieve your output.

```
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>and</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

**PS**

to see result, see view source you it will look a like this.
[image: This]